# Enhance vocal percussion / beatboxing

Tags: audio-recording, drum

I'm looking for a way to enhance the vocal percussion (i.e., beatboxing) of some acapella recordings--[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMjKNM_Q3S0) is the one I'm working on at the moment.  I realize I'm not going to be able to isolate it entirely, but anything I could do to make it sound more prominent will be helpful.  It's only for my own learning (beatboxing, not sound engineering) so it doesn't have to be perfect.  I am a complete novice with regards to sound design.  I have GarageBand, but I'd be willing to purchase something else if it did the job and were reasonably priced.

Answer (score 1):

I had a go with a transient shaper & multi-band compressor, but tbh the track is already finished, mastered, finalised & compressed for market; it doesn't leave you a lot of space to play with.

I pushed the transients 18 dB & all I got was... transients.
There's too much 'track' to really be able to isolate it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what anything you said means

Comment: Basically... if you want to practise beat-box, find beat-box tracks, not finished records ;)

Comment: Thanks but I'm specifically trying to hear what this person is doing on this song.  Not sure if the answer to "How do I do X" is "You should just do Y instead."

Comment: Then the answer becomes - use a transient shaper... not that it will really help much, but it will make the transients louder. idk if you can get hold of one cheap/free to play with, I use Waves plugins, which are not cheap.